# PYCord How can I get message by view?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/977648291770667010/977648292206903336/unknown.png

As you can see in the screen shot, there is an explanation about how to edit content of the message when timeout expires in official PyCord website.

But as you can see in this screenshot:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/977648291770667010/977648292655677440/unknown.png

PyCharm says there is no field called "message".

It appears the same error when debug it:

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/977648291770667010/977651067007426670/unknown.png?width=1200&height=123

Here is my code:

````py
    class UIAgreement(View):

    def __init__(self, client: Stragate):
        super().__init__(timeout=10)
        self.client = client

    async def on_timeout(self):

        self.disable_all_items()

        await self.message.edit(content="You took too long! Try again.", view=self)

    @button(label="Accept", style=ButtonStyle.success, emoji="")
    async def accept_callback(self, event_button: Button, event_interaction: Interaction):

        cursor = self.client.database.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE id={event_interaction.user.id} LIMIT 1")

        if not cursor.fetchone():
            cursor = self.client.database.cursor()

            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO profiles (id, full_name, job, country, description, thumbnail, "
                           "gender) VALUES (%s, %s, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, %s, DEFAULT)",
                           (
                               event_interaction.user.id,
                               event_interaction.user.display_name,
                               "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/976061052548694036"
                               "/977291014047936552/default.jpg"
                           ))
            self.client.database.commit()

            await event_interaction.user.send(embed=Embed(
                title="Successfully registered!",
                description="Please use the 'start' command again."
            ))```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymKyQ.png
````

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned "Message" field is a field that I need to set out of scope. That's what they said in their discord server. I guess guide is a little bit outdated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).